# why does the result of the clojure fn include parentheses?

Tags: clojure

the following code is my answer for http://www.4clojure.com/problem/108. But the result includes parentheses.
I cannot figure out the problem.

```
(
(fn abc [& cs]
  (let [ fs (first (take 1 (apply map (fn [& vs] vs) cs)))
         fi (apply min fs)
         fx (apply max fs)]
    (if 
      (= fi fx) fi
      (for [n (range (count fs)) :when (= fi (nth fs n))]
         (apply abc (concat (take n cs) (vector (rest (nth cs n))) (drop (inc n) cs)))))))

[1 2 3 4 5 6 7] [4 19])
```

the result is **(((4)))**, but the expected result is **4**.

thank you.

Comment: `for` returns a sequence.

Comment: @Lee could you add this as an answer so we can mark this question as answered?